# Load more button script: image instead of text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been building a plugin for my theme, to replace the standard navigation to a simple load more button.

However I would like to change the button into a png image of a plus.
I only can get the script so far that it displays the link to the image, instead of showing it.

I'm fairly new at this so I was javascript thing so I was wondering if anybody could give me a hint ?

the plugin works with a loadmore.js file and an index.php file

loadmore.js:

```
if ( next_page <= max_pages ) {
    $( '.paging-navigation' ).html( '<div class="nav-links"><a class="load_more" href="#">' + _load_more.main_img + '</a><img class="load_more_img" style="display: none;" src="' + _load_more.loading_img + '" alt="Loading..." /></div>' );
}

var mt_ajax_load_posts = function() {
    //Begin Ajax
    $.post( _load_more.ajaxurl, { action: 'load_posts', next_page: next_page }, function( response ) {
        next_page = response.next_page;
        max_pages = response.max_pages;

        //Append the HTML
        var html = $.parseHTML( response.html );
        html = $( html ).filter( '.type-post' );
        $( '#content .type-post:last' ).after( html );

        //If the next page exceeds the number of pages available, get rid of the navigation
        if ( next_page > max_pages ) {
            $( '.paging-navigation' ).html( '' );
        }

        //Fade out loading img and fade in loading text
        $( '.load_more_img' ).fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
            $( '.load_more' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
        } );
    }, 'json' );
};

//Clicking the load more button
$( '.paging-navigation' ).on( 'click', 'a.load_more', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $( '.load_more' ).fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
        $( '.load_more_img' ).fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
            mt_ajax_load_posts();
        } );
    } );


} );
```

index.php file

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', '_load_more_textdomain' );
function _load_more_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'HelloDolly-load-more', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}

/* Load More */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_load_more_scripts' );
function _load_more_scripts() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( !is_home() ) return;

    //Detect HelloDolly
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $template = $theme->get_template();
    if ( 'HelloDolly' != $template ) return;

    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    wp_enqueue_script( '-load-more', plugins_url( '/js/loadmore.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '20131010', true );
    wp_localize_script( '-load-more', '_load_more', array(
        'current_page' => esc_js( $paged ),
        'max_pages' => esc_js( $max ),
        'ajaxurl' => esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ),
        'main_img' => esc_js( plugins_url( '/images/plus.png', __FILE__ ) ),
        'loading_img' => esc_js( plugins_url( '/images/ajax-loader.gif', __FILE__ ) )
    ) );
}
/**
 * Ajax for loading more posts
 * 
 * @author Ronald Huereca <ronald@metronet.no> 
 */
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_posts', '_ajax_load_posts' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts', '_ajax_load_posts' );
 function _ajax_load_posts() {
    $next_page = absint( $_POST[ 'next_page' ] );

    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'paged' => $next_page,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ) );
    ob_start();
    global $post;
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $wp_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    };
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    $return_array = array(
        'next_page' => $next_page + 1,
        'max_pages' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'html' => $html
    );
    //return
    die( json_encode( $return_array ) );
 } //end _ajax_load_posts

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dumping a lot of not useful information into this question.
You need to be more clear and focus into the real issue. 
DO you want to put an image in a button, or make an image to act as a button?
Do you want to do this in Javascript, jQuery or in PHP code?

Comment: sorry, just wanted to be as complete as possible. I would like the image to act as the button. When clicked upon it should load the next posts. And if possible in javascript since most of the plugin is written in javascript.  Though if impossible or too difficult jquery or php will do just as fine.

Comment: If your image class is **load_more_img**, what you need to do with jQyery is this:
`$('.load_more_img').on('click',function(){
     mt_ajax_load_posts(); // regarding this is the function you need to call
)};
`

Comment: the plus image has a class called main_img, defined in the quary as this: 'main_img' => esc_js( plugins_url( '/images/plus.png', __FILE__ ) )     

the load_more_img is what happens when a user clicks on the link, displaying a loading gif (spinning circle)

I've added the code you suggested (with altering load_more_img to main_img) but I think I need to add the image itself into the paging navigation between the <a> tags, but so far no luck